# Adding post_class into functions.php query

Tags: post-class

Obvious newbie question I'm sure. Working on a friend's site and trying to figure out how to add post_class to a query. Just adding  works fine and adds the div, but I don't know how to get it to run the `"id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>"` part of it instead of echoing it.

```
$sidebar .= sprintf('<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>><p><span class="CityCountry">%s</span>' . chr(13),
```

I'm sure it's a formatting thing of some sort that I don't know yet... still so much to learn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `post_class()` will echo the class in the format `class="postclassA
  postclassB"`
- `get_post_class()` will return an array of all registred
  classes

To use `get_post_class()` inside `sprintf()`, you have to return the array as a string. For this purpose you can use the `join()` function.

### Example

```
$classes = join(' ', get_post_class())
$sidebar = sprintf('<div id="post-%s" class="%s">%s</div>', get_the_ID(), $classes, get_the_content());
```